# Windows features listing in VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript

I had problems with a code to list the features of windows 7 x64, so far I have been testing with the following code , I hope you can help

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
comspec = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%comspec%")

Set objShell2 = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec(comspec & " /k dism /online /get-features")
 Do
    line = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
    s = s & line & vbcrlf
Loop While Not objExec.Stdout.atEndOfStream
WScript.Echo s
```

Comment: Welcome at stackoverflow. Without knowing what _problems_  you   have encountered, try `/C` switch: `.Exec(comspec & " /C dism /online /get-features")`. Read `cmd /?`.

Comment: very grateful, when I run the script it does not work, asks for elevated privileges for dism, I could not run the dism with privilege

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your "*I could not run the dism with privilege*". Next script auto elevates itself if possible:

```
Option Explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim objShell, comspec, objShell2, objExec, line, s, sErrLine
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
comspec = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%comspec%")
sErrLine = ""
Set objShell2 = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec(comspec _
  & " /V:ON /c dism /online /Format:Table /get-features" _
  & "||echo error=!errorlevel! occurred&exit")
Do
    line = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
    If line = "error=740 occurred" Then sErrLine = line
    s = s & line & vbcrlf
Loop While Not objExec.Stdout.atEndOfStream
If sErrLine = "" Then
  WScript.Echo s
Else
  If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("autoelevated") Then
    WScript.Echo s & vbNewLine & "Auto elevate failed, try 'Run as administrator'"
  Else
    If InStr(1, Wscript.FullName, "WSCript.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      ' auto elevate if current host is WSCript
      objShell2.ShellExecute Wscript.FullName _
        , Wscript.ScriptFullName & " /autoelevated", "", "runas", 1
      ' another way of auto elevate if default host is WSCript
      ' objShell2.ShellExecute Wscript.ScriptFullName, " /autoelevated", "", "runas", 1
    ElseIf InStr(1, Wscript.FullName, "CSCript.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      ' auto elevate if current host is CSCript (invokes another 'cmd' instance)
      objShell2.ShellExecute comspec, " /K " _
        & Wscript.FullName & " " & Wscript.ScriptFullName & " /autoelevated" _
          , "", "runas", 1
    Else
      WScript.Echo s & vbNewLine & "Can't auto elevate, try 'Run as administrator'"
    End If
  End If
End If
```

Comment: thank very much, the code generates an error followed, decided to run from a batch this work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
comspec = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%comspec%")

Set objShell2 = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objExec = objShell.shellExec "comspec",  " /k dism /online /get-features" 
', <dir (if any, if not leave blank)>, <verb (ie. runas, etc.)>, 
' <window style>
' normal=1, hide=0, 2=Min, 3=max, 4=restore, 5=current, 7=min/inactive, 10=default
 Do
    line = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
    s = s & line & vbcrlf
Loop While Not objExec.Stdout.atEndOfStream
WScript.Echo s
```